# PHP: Ajax Post URL is Failing to hit the php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am developing an php application to create an user information. I am using jquery ajax call to hit php server but the hit is not occurred. Following is my code,

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "create.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: datastring,
  cache: false,
  success: function (response) {
  alert( JSON.stringify(response) );
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert(errorThrown);
  }
  });
```

And my php file is,

```
try {
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$name = $data["name"];
$email = $data['email'];
$mobile = $data['mobile'];

$stmt = $connection->prepare("query");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

} catch (Exception $e) {
$msg = array("status" =>0 , "msg" => $e->errorMessage());
}
```

Please someone guide me to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to open your http://localhost/create.php ? You should have a 200 HTTP Status code before proceeding with the ajax call